What distribution does $\frac{\theta^x}{(1+\theta)^{1+x}}$ match?
$f_\theta(x) = \frac{\theta^x}{(1+\theta)^{1+x}}, x\in\mathbb{N}, \theta\in(0,\infty)$
I was supposed to find an estimator using MLE and the method of moments. I thought the function eerily matched a geometric distribution with the parameter $\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$ but not quite.
Understanding what distribution the function matches could help me find its mean and apply the method of moments.

Sorry about that, I updated the question.

Geometric distribution (shifted version).

Your $\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$ presumably comes from seeing $\frac{P(X=x+1)}{P(X=x)}=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$.  But for a geometric distribution $\frac{P(X=x+1)}{P(X=x)}$ is $1-p$ rather than $p$, so you get $p=1-\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}=\frac{1}{\theta+1}$ as you seem to have found.

A geometric distribution $p(1-p)^x$ where $p = \frac{1}{\theta+1}$ was what I was looking for in the end.
Knowing the theoretical mean is $E(X) = \frac{1-p}{p}$ I got the estimator $\hat\theta = \overline{X}$ like so:
$E(X) = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{\theta+1}}{\frac{1}{\theta+1}} = \theta$
